# Copying Directories in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to copy a directory from a location to other location and i have written code for that. On executing the IDE is giving me an exception.

```
import sys
import os
from Tkinter import *
from tkCommonDialog import Dialog
import shutil
import tkFileDialog
import win32com.client

win = Tk()
win.title("Copying the Dorectory to specified location")
win.geometry("600x600+200+50")
win.resizable()
class Copy:

    def __init__(self,Obj):

        la = Label(win, text = "Source Directory is",font = "verdana 12 italic bold", width = 20,fg = "Red", bg = "WHITE", )
        la.grid(row=1, column =1)
        abc = "tk_chooseDirectory"
        bu = Button(text="Source", font = "Verdana 12 italic", command= abc )
        bu.grid(row =1 , column =3)


        la1 = Label(win, text = "DestibationDirectory is",font = "verdana 12 italic bold", width = 20,fg = "Red", bg = "WHITE", )
        la1.grid(row=2, column =1)
        abc1 = "tk_chooseDirectory"
        bu1 = Button(text="Destination", font = "Verdana 12 italic", command=abc1)
        bu1.grid(row =2 , column =3)


        def start():
            shutil.copy(abc, abc1)
        bu2 = Button(text="Copy", font= "Verdana 12 bold", command =start)
        bu2.grid(row =3, column =2)

obj = Copy(win)
win.mainloop()
```

This is my code and the exception that I am facing is

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Bharath Gupta\Desktop\task.py", line 38, in start
    shutil.copy(abc, abc1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 116, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 68, in copyfile
    raise Error("`%s` and `%s` are the same file" % (src, dst))
Error: `tk_chooseDirectory` and `tk_chooseDirectory` are the same file
```

Please some one help me to get rid of the exception.

Comment: Use `shutil.copytree` to copy entire directories.

Comment: Friend Finally I got the ans to my Quesn;;; Thats very simple we should call the variable with the class name specification like """classname.variablename"""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code you have, with a few added comments by me.

```
class Copy:
    def __init__(self,Obj):
        la = Label(win, text = "Source Directory is",font = "verdana 12 italic bold", width = 20,fg = "Red", bg = "WHITE", )
        la.grid(row=1, column =1)
        #SET abc HERE
        abc = "tk_chooseDirectory"
        bu = Button(text="Source", font = "Verdana 12 italic", command= abc )
        bu.grid(row =1 , column =3)


        la1 = Label(win, text = "DestibationDirectory is",font = "verdana 12 italic bold", width = 20,fg = "Red", bg = "WHITE", )
        la1.grid(row=2, column =1)
        #SET abc1 HERE
        abc1 = "tk_chooseDirectory"
        bu1 = Button(text="Destination", font = "Verdana 12 italic", command=abc1)
        bu1.grid(row =2 , column =3)


        def start():
            #RUN WITH abc AND abc1
            shutil.copy(abc, abc1)
```

But you never change the values of those variables. Since you initialize them to the same thing. Your copy command is trying to copy something to itself. (Which is what the error says:

> Error: `tk_chooseDirectory` and `tk_chooseDirectory` are the same file

You need a way to enter in the two directories you want to use so that `shutil.copy()` will do what you want.

Comment: unholysampler@ can u please elaborate the ans. tk_chooseDirectory is used to select the directories.

Comment: @BharathGupta: The button uses that as the callback function. The problem is that callback just opens the dialog and allows you to select a directory. It __does not__ save that result into into the variable you happened to use to initialize the button.

Comment: Thats so nice of u dude.And now how could I store the path that I select using the tk_ChooseDirectory.

Comment: @BharathGupta: Write a method that calls `tk_ChooseDirectory` and saves the result into an instance variable. Use that as the callback method.

Comment: Friend Finally I got the ans to my Quesn;;; Thats very simple we should call the variable with the class name specification like """classname.variablename" ""

Answer (score 1):

> Please some one help me to get rid of the exception.

A sure-fire way to get rid of exceptions is this pattern:

```
try:
    #shutil naughtiness
except:
    pass
```

...but that one's sure to draw your colleagues' ire.

It looks like in your particular case the source and destination are the very same.  It seems like the most appropriate thing to do in this case is to **handle** the exception.  Especially since this is only one of many failure modes of the copy.  You should escalate each of them to the user, since the user should know how to resolve it.

You're in the enviable position that your code is likely well-equipped to handle the exception.  Try

```
try:
    shutil.copy(abc, abc1)
except Error, e:
    tkMessageBox.showwarning(
        "Copying file",
        "Error while copying\n(%s)" % e.msg
    )
```

Comment: try:
    shutil.copy(abc, abc1)
except :
    tkMessageBox.showwarning(
        "Copying file",
        "Error while copying\n(%s)" 
    )

Dude this is the change that I have done.On running the file it is giving me an error and what should i do to copy my directory to other.

Please please help me in this aspect

Comment: Dude, the user should see the error and take corrective action.  The exception handler above does this.  The user will see "tk_chooseDirectory and tk_chooseDirectory are the same file" and realize, "Oops!  I can't copy a file onto itself.  That's silly."

Comment: @Brain Chain. This is right but now If i wanna copy., How could I progress and whats the method to do.Please give me a clear idea. Thanks

Comment: Friend Finally I got the ans to my Quesn;;; Thats very simple we should call the variable with the class name specification like """classname.variablename""

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import os
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
from tkCommonDialog import Dialog
import shutil
import tkFileDialog
import win32com.client

win = Tk()
win.title("Copying the Directory to specified location")
win.geometry("600x600+200+50")
win.resizable()


class Copy(object):


    def __init__(self):
        def srce():

            self.src = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(title="The source folder is ")
            textboxsrc.delete(0, END)
            textboxsrc.insert(0, self.src)
            print self.src
            return self.src

        textboxsrc = Entry(win, width="70")
        textboxsrc.insert(0, 'Enter master file name')
        textboxsrc.pack()
        textboxsrc.place(relx=0.40, rely=0.06, anchor=CENTER)
        bu = Button(text="Source", font="Verdana 12 italic bold", bg="Purple", fg="white", command=srce)
        bu.pack(fill=X, expand=YES)
        bu.place(relx=0.85, rely=0.06, anchor=CENTER)

        def dest():
            self.des = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(title="TheDestination folder is ")
            textboxdes.delete(0, END)
            textboxdes.insert(0, self.des)
            print self.des
            return self.des

        textboxdes = Entry(win, width="70")
        textboxdes.insert(0, 'Enter master file name')
        textboxdes.pack()
        textboxdes.place(relx=0.40, rely=0.13, anchor=CENTER)
        bu1 = Button(text="Destination", font="Verdana 12 italic", bg="Purple", fg="white", command=dest)
        bu1.pack(fill=X, expand=YES)
        bu1.place(relx=0.85, rely=0.13, anchor=CENTER)

        def start():


            try:
                shutil.copytree(self.src, self.des)
            except :
                tkMessageBox.showwarning("Copying file", "Error while copying\n(%s)")

        bn = Button(text="Copy", font="Verdana 12 italic", bg="Purple", fg="white", command=start)
        bn.pack(fill=X, expand=YES)
        bn.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.25, anchor=CENTER)

obj = Copy()
#obj.source(win)
#obj.destination(win)
win.mainloop()
```